# How to use lazyload +pagination + sort+ filter in p-Table using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a p-table, where in i am using lazyload, pagination,sort and filter in my application.
I managed to make work sort, filter along with lazy load. Now my issue is with pagination.

the items gets loaded accordingly, and for eg. i have 3 pages of data so totally 30 i have.
If i go to sort or filter the data, then instead of showing 3 pages, it gives me only that page of data on which i tried to sort. rest 2 pages wont display. In pagination, i get 1, insted of 1,2,3.

Help needed.

HTML:

```
<p-table [columns]="tableHeaders" [value]="listEmrAllergy " [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" (onLazyLoad)="loadLazy($event)"
    [totalRecords]="totalcount" [lazy]="!press" #tt [globalFilterFields]="tableHeaders">
    <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
      <div style="text-align: right">
        <label>Search:</label>
        <input type="text" pInputText size="25" (keypress)="press=true" [ngModel]="alpha" (ngModelChange)="searchCheck($event)" class="filter"
          style="width:auto" (input)="tt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" autocomplete='off'>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
                {{col.header}}
                <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field" ariaLabel="Activate to sort" ariaLabelDesc="Activate to sort in descending order" ariaLabelAsc="Activate to sort in ascending order">sooort</p-sortIcon>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

TS:

```
    public searchCheck(evt) {
        evt.length > 0 ? this.press = true :
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.press = false
          }, 400);
      }

      public loadLazy(LazyLoadEvent) {
        console.log(LazyLoadEvent);
        const count = (LazyLoadEvent.first + 10) / 10;
        this.pageNo = Math.ceil(count);
        if (LazyLoadEvent.sortField) {
          this.sort(LazyLoadEvent.sortField, LazyLoadEvent.sortOrder);
        }
        else {
          this.interactionHistories;
        }
      }


      private sort(fieldName: string, order: number) {
        this.listEmrAllergy.sort((row1, row2) => {
          const val1 = row1[fieldName];
          const val2 = row2[fieldName];
          if (val1 === val2) {
            return 0;
          }
          let result = -1;
          if (val1 > val2) {
            result = 1;
          }
          if (order < 0) {
            result = -result;
          }
          return result;
        });
      }

 private getEmrAllergyList() {
let params = { 'Id': this.userId, PageNo: this.pageNo, PageSize: 10 }
this.emrService.getEmrAllergy(params)
  .subscribe(allergyLists => {
    this.listEmrAllergy = allergyLists.Body.Data.Items;
    this.totalcount = allergyLists.Body.Data.TotalItemCount;
    console.log(this.listEmrAllergy);
  })
    this.emrNavigation.getTotalList();
```

}

Comment: I think you are doing client side filtering and sorting, you should do it server side

Comment: @Sravan thanks for response, how can that be done

Comment: client side, sorting and filtering is working but when comes to pagination it is not working, may be bcz of lazy loading

Comment: what is lazy load, I never used `p-table` i just said logically to use server side

Comment: what u said is actually correct, p-table is jus lyk *ngFor only using primeng and lazy loading , is to load the data according to page number

Comment: I never used that `p-table` you are taking about, so I m unable to help you

Comment: Thanks for response

Comment: Give me if any plugin for that, or any reference and explain your problem more detail

Comment: @Sravan Thanks for helping me, from which point u need explanation pls tel i will tel in detail